# R variable not found, but specifically defined

Tags: r, function

I have written a function to run phylogenetic generalized least squares, and everything looks like it should work fine, but for some reason, a specific variable which is defined in the script (W) keeps coming up as undefined. I have stared at this code for hours and cannot figure out where the problem is.

Any ideas?

```
myou <- function(alpha, datax, datay, tree){
    data.frame(datax[tree$tip.label,],datay[tree$tip.label,],row.names=tree$tip.label)->dat
    colnames(dat)<-c("Trait1","Trait2")
    W<-diag(vcv.phylo(tree)) # Weights
    fm <- gls(Trait1 ~ Trait2, data=dat, correlation = corMartins(alpha, tree, fixed = TRUE),weights = ~ W,method = "REML")
    return(as.numeric(fm$logLik))
}

corMartins2<-function(datax, datay, tree){
    data.frame(datax[tree$tip.label,],datay[tree$tip.label,],row.names=tree$tip.label)->dat
    colnames(dat)<-c("Trait1","Trait2")
    result <- optimize(f = myou, interval = c(0, 4), datax=datax,datay=datay, tree = tree, maximum = TRUE)
    W<-diag(vcv.phylo(tree)) # Weights
    fm <- gls(Trait1 ~ Trait2, data = dat, correlation = corMartins(result$maximum, tree, fixed =T),weights = ~ W,method = "REML")
    list(fm, result$maximum)}




#test


require(nlme)
require(phytools)
simtree<-rcoal(50)
as.data.frame(fastBM(simtree))->dat1
as.data.frame(fastBM(simtree))->dat2

corMartins2(dat1,dat2,tree=simtree)
```

returns "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'W' not found"

even though W is specifically defined!

Thanks!

Comment: What are `lowerB` and `upperB`?

Comment: Debugging code that one can't run on one's own computer is a special circle of hell that I generally aim to avoid.

Comment: You probably want `cbind(dat, W)` in the `corMartins2()` function. I think `gls()` is looking for `W` in the `dat` data.frame and not finding it.

Comment: sorry about that, I removed lowerB and upperB and replaced them with hard-coded values. Also, this should be a runable script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error's occuring in the `gls` calls in `myou` and `corMatrins2`: you have to pass in `W` as a column in `dat` because `gls` is looking for it there (when you put `weights = ~W` as a formula like that it looks for `dat$W` and can't find it).

Just change `data=dat` to `data=cbind(dat,W=W)` in both functions.

Comment: Thanks for the fix! This makes complete sense!

Answer (score 5):

The example is not reproducible for me, as `lowerB` and `upperB` are not defined, however, perhaps the following will work for you, `cbinding` `dat` with `W`:

```
myou <- function(alpha, datax, datay, tree){
    data.frame(datax[tree$tip.label,],datay[tree$tip.label,],row.names=tree$tip.label)->dat
    colnames(dat)<-c("Trait1","Trait2")
    W<-diag(vcv.phylo(tree)) # Weights
            ### cbind W to dat
            dat <- cbind(dat, W = W)
    fm <- gls(Trait1 ~ Trait2, data=dat, correlation = corMartins(alpha, tree, fixed = TRUE),weights = ~ W,method = "REML")
    return(as.numeric(fm$logLik))
}

corMartins2<-function(datax, datay, tree){
    data.frame(datax[tree$tip.label,],datay[tree$tip.label,],row.names=tree$tip.label)->dat
    colnames(dat)<-c("Trait1","Trait2")
    result <- optimize(f = myou, interval = c(lowerB, upperB), datax=datax,datay=datay, tree = tree, maximum = TRUE)
    W<-diag(vcv.phylo(tree)) # Weights
    ### cbind W to dat
    dat <- cbind(dat, W = W)
    fm <- gls(Trait1 ~ Trait2, data = dat, correlation = corMartins(result$maximum, tree, fixed =T),weights = ~ W,method = "REML")
    list(fm, result$maximum)}




#test
require(phytools)
simtree<-rcoal(50)
as.data.frame(fastBM(simtree))->dat1
as.data.frame(fastBM(simtree))->dat2

corMartins2(dat1,dat2,tree=simtree)
```

Comment: yeah that was the problem...thanks for taking the time to help me!